# insert link in wordpress editor greyout whole screen?

Tags: links, visual-editor, html-editor

Pulling my hair with this strange issue. When I want to insert link in wordpress page or post, my whole page screen is greyed out, and insert link feature dont work. I tried to disable plugins, insert fresh files for tinymce, install several others editors... But, nothing.
Issue is same on both, visual and html editor.

Please help and thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to use another browser or a virgin browser profile without any plugins installed?

Comment: I tried different browser and got same result.virgin browser profile is unknown to me:-(

Comment: Does your console show any errors?

Comment: yes. 

TypeError: this._super is not a function
http://www.redcoats.co.uk/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpdialogs/js/wpdialog.js?ver=3.4.1
Line 22

Comment: @s_ha_dum any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to update jQuery. You are running

`/*! jQuery v1.8.3 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */`

and [a very quick search of the error message text](https://www.google.com/search?q=this._super%20is%20not%20a%20function) lead to this, posted five months ago-- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/1794--, and to the simple instructions "You need to upgrade to jquery-ui 1.9".

I would suggest updating your install as a whole: http://www.redcoats.co.uk/readme.html